# How do format specifiers work internally?

Tags: c

Consider:

```
int x=0xdeadbeef;
char c=x;
printf("%x",c);
```

The output is `ffffffef`.
How? Why is it NOT `000000ef`?

Answer (score 4):

A 32-bit integer does not fit inside an 8-bit char so `char c=x;` is the same as `c=0xef`.

Then apparently `char` is signed on your compiler and `0xef` is larger than 127, so it gets converted to some negative value, -17.

When passed to `printf`, the negative value `char` gets promoted to `int`, the sign is preserved (this is called "default argument promotion" and is used by all variadic functions). The 32-bit two's complement representation -17 is `ffffffef`. With `%x` you use the wrong format specifier; `printf` expects `unsigned int`. It tries to display the signed number as unsigned.

You can fix the bug by replacing `char` with `uint8_t`.

Overall, this code is very questionable, since it relies on lots of poorly-specified behavior. You shouldn't overflow signed integers, you shouldn't use `char` for storing values, you should make an effort at using the correct format specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

This is less a question of "how to format specifiers work" and more a "how does `char` work".

A `char` without any other type information can be either a signed or an unsigned value, which one is compiler-dependent. If you want a specific signedness, you should use `unsigned char` or `signed char`.

The `%x` format instruction expects an unsigned int, so will (essentially) cast the char first to an int, then interpret that as an unsigned int. If your char is signed, it will get sign-extended as it's converted to an int and that's why you get the value you are seeing.